# is there a simple, efficient way to download (open) 5000+ images from google storage to a python notebook?

Tags: python, image, google-cloud-platform, download, storage

I have a jupyter notebook (python) running at google AI platform.
in order to read a file into the notebook from google storage i'm using :

```py
blob = storage.blob.Blob(filename,bucket)
content = blob.download_to_filename(filename)
```

is there a simple way to point to a bucket directory and make reading 5K+ images more easier, efficient and transparent to the pipeline?
thanks, N

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `gsutil` command with parallelism:

```
!gcloud -m cp gs://<your bucket>/* /<your local path>/
```

Add `-r` if the images are also in subdirectory. [Here a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3azwgwx_X2g&list=PLIivdWyY5sqJcBvDh5dfPoblLGhG1R1-O&index=5&t=0s)

If the download is still slow, look at the number of vCPU that you have for your notebook. The bandwidth is limited to 2Gbps per vCPU up to 8 vCPU.

For increasing again the performance, take care of hotspots. Indeed, if the names of your image are too similar, it's the same shard which serve it and you have contention. [Here a video which describe this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-XDw55qUzs&list=PLIivdWyY5sqJcBvDh5dfPoblLGhG1R1-O&index=11&t=0s)

However, generally, it's not required to have all the images in your Jupiter Notebook. You have to perform/validate your model on a small set of data before running it on dedicated server and to really train your model.

Comment: hi thanks! this should work... but i'd like to refine the question:   !pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" [directory] , how can i refer to a directory in google buckets without downloading the files in the notebook ?

Comment: You can use [FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse). It creates a mounting point in your file system and communicates by API with Cloud Storage. I repeat, **communicates by API with Cloud Storage**. It's not without impact in term of performance (API latency) and pricing (each query is a class A request). And for training the files are read many, many, many times! Finally you will pay useless processing time because of latency and file access to storage. Think smart before using this!